# Fill NaN value after grouping twice

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, fillna

**Dummy data  :**

```
code = ['a','a','a','a','b','b']
serial  =  ['x','y','x','y','x','y']
result = [123,  np.nan, 453, 675, 786, 332]

  code serial  result
0  a    x      123.0 
1  a    y     NaN    
2  a    x      453.0 
3  a    y      675.0 
4  b    x      786.0 
5  b    y      332.0
```

I want to fill NaN with 675.0, first group by `code` then by `serial` and fill the NaN value

**Code:**

```
df['result'] = df['result'].fillna(df.groupby('code')['result'].ffill())
```

In the code above; I want to integrate `.groupby('serial')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `groupby` both columns at the same time:

```
df['result'] = df.groupby(['code', 'serial'])['result'].bfill()
df
```

Output:

```
  code serial  result
0    a      x   123.0
1    a      y   675.0
2    a      x   453.0
3    a      y   675.0
4    b      x   786.0
5    b      y   332.0
```

P.S. You would need to `bfill` instead of `ffill` it though, since that `NaN` comes before the first value in the group

Comment: actually I apply both `bfill` and  `bfill` in 2 separate code, somtime NaN comes before and after the value

Answer (score 2):

Use -

```
df['result'].fillna(df.groupby(['code', 'serial'])['result'].transform('first'))
```

**Output**

```
0    123
1    675
2    453
3    675
4    786
5    332
Name: result, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hm, that's the same solution as what Quang Hoang posted a bit earlier, is it not?

Comment: @perl rest assured we independently arrived at that...my screen didn't refresh at the time of posting

Comment: @perl If you check the timestamps in fact Vivek is 20 sec faster. This happens a lot in SO, sometimes answers are not rendering while writing an answer. Both of them good contributors upvoted both of the answers.

Comment: Sure, I'm cool with that, just don't think it's worth having two answers with the same solution for the same question. I normally delete mine if it's the same as someone else's and someone else posted it earlier